# Unlock Login Keyring starts with chrome problem of unrecognised password

Tags: login, google-chrome, password, chromium

I've already read all the others threads about this issue. Nothing worked so far.

I can't change the password on the Key And Password application because my old password is not recognised. 
I had this issue for a long time and just lived with it as long as I was using Firefox which didn't popped this window.But to watch amazon videos, CHROME is required and the popup window appears each time I launch the browser, with Chromium too.

Any simple suggestion is welcome.

I thought of uninstalling the Key and Password app and reinstalling it but I am afraid that it might mess up with my session login.

Comment: No, Chrome **isn't** required for Amazon Prime. The first time in Firefox it'll ask to enable DRM (disabled by default) and that's it!

Comment: Very right! Thanks. It doesn't resolve the matter of password but it is no longer a problem if I use Firefox instead.